# Python/Pandas bug detecting string

Tags: python, excel, pandas, string, dataframe

I am working on some code with pandas and I am having a really weird issue. In the code lines I show on this post I am trying to get a dataframe for each "product" (this is the column name) separately and export each dataframe to a new sheet in a new excel workbook. Now, it works just fine with certain products, but I'm having an issue with the ones such as "GDAES_D+1". Every df that finds a string that contains a "+#" (# being a number) returns an emtpy dataframe. Is this some sort of bug or something like that? Is +1, +2, etc... something specific inside a string in python? I am very much confused and I would appreciate tons any help you can give me.

I would also like to learn what's behind this issue because it looks like something I should know (if it's not a bug or similar)

```
# PVB
df = hoja_PVB[hoja_PVB['Product'].str.contains('GWDES', na=False)]
df.drop(df.columns[[2,3,4]], axis = 1)
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'GWDES', index = False) #This one, 'GWDES' has no +# and works perfectly

df = hoja_PVB[hoja_PVB['Product'].str.contains('GDAES_D+1', na=False)] 
df.drop(df.columns[[2,3,4]], axis = 1)
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'GDAES_D+1', index = False) #This one, 'GDAES_D+1' returns an empty dataframe.
#I can asure you the original dataframe has plenty of data for this product, it's not empty.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.contains`](https://regex101.com/r/QFI8zB/1) uses regex patterns. `+` in regex has a special meaning of "one or more of previous characters". So, you are in fact looking for strings like "GDAES_D1", "GDAES_DD1", etc. If you want to search for literals, you need to escape all regex special characters by using `\` - full pattern would be `"GDAES_D\+1"` - https://regex101.com/r/QFI8zB/1

Alternatively, you can change `regex` parameter from True (default) to False - `.str.contains('GDAES_D+1', na=False, regex=False)`

Comment: Thank you very much, really interesting to know.